# How to get current category id in patterns of templates/category.html in WordPress 6

Tags: wordpress-theming

I create a new theme, folder structure as follows:

```
- themes/
-- orgcms/
--- patterns/category-sidebar.php
--- templates/category.html
...
```

Add pattern to category.html:

```
<!-- wp:pattern {"slug": "orgcms/category-sidebar"} /-->
```

And then, try to get current category id in patterns/category-sidebar.php:

```
<?php
/**
 * Title: Category's Sidebar
 * Slug: orgcms/category-sidebar
 */
?>

<?php
echo var_dump(get_queried_object());
?>
```

However, I get `NULL` on category archive page(**templates/category.html**).

`get_query_var('cat')` also get empty value.

Thanks for any help.